# Lucene nested queries

Tags: lucene

I have this situation

```
Entity Company_id 
-----------------
E001     1        
E001     2       
E003     1
E002     2
E001     3
E003     3
```

I want to know how much companies that have entities (E001 and E003) in this case the result should be company 1 and 3.

In SQL it can be resolved by making a nested query but I should use something like luncene because of performance needs this query will be executed more that 50 times for each page.

Note : I can have to restrict on 3 or 4 entities also ex : all companies that have (E001 AND E002 AND E003 AND 3004).

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT**
I know that lucene is made for text search but let's suppose that each row is a Document in the index.

Comment: Lucene is not a relational database - its a text search engine specifically designed for scenarios involving full-text search queries, not for querying data.  This looks like a data querying scenario to me, in which case you would be better using a relational database (e.g. SQL)

Comment: Can't use SQL .. Let's suppose that each row is an instance of document. How to do that ?

Comment: I beleive @Justin is correct, the case you describe is a poor fit for Lucene, ESPECIALLY for the document definition you have described.  Lucene handles joins anywhere from very-poorly to not-at-all depending on how you use it.  I don't care if you use a traditional RDBMS or a nifty NoSQL implementation, or what, but the implementation as you put it here isn't really very workable..

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But can we think about it as an intersection of 2 query results ? is there any way to do that natively in lucene ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure your Lucene index so that each company is a Lucene document and they contain 0 or more entities, then (in query parser syntax) "all companies with E001 AND E003" becomes:

```
+entity:E001 +entity:E003
```

(where **entity** is the entity field). "All companies with E001 AND E002 AND E003 AND E004 becomes:

+entity:E001 +entity:E002 +entity:E003 +entity:E004

Then just include "Company_id" as a stored field for the Company document, so you can see it in the query results.

Comment: Yes that's the multiple boolean queries being fired inside the same single boolean query. Else can we possibly use MultiTerm Query or something like that..